# Looking for specific Sales Dataset

Tags: data-request, programming, companies, analysis

I am relatively new to programming and therefore don't really know where to find specified datasets. What I am basically looking for is Sales Data from any Company (can be made up).

The data needs have coverage of the number of clients, the amount of money they paid and the date for each transaction. I want to predict the worth of each customer with this information, using the RFM-method on R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example with full R code here: [RFM Customer Analysis with R Language](http://www.dataapple.net/?p=84)

You can find the accompanying dataset here: http://brucehardie.com/datasets/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the dataset provided by vonjd, you can look at the Online retail and Online retail II datasets on the UC irvine data repository.

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/online+retail
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Online+Retail+II

They contain transaction data for an online retailer that can be used to derive the Recency, Frequency and Monetary variables for each customer.